# What is $y^{(n)}$, and how do I find it?

Tags: notation, derivatives

The question : Find $y^{(n)}(x)$  if $y(x)=\frac{1}{2-x}$... there is no explanation for $y^{(n)}$ in my textbook...can you explain this to me? 
First I tried to find the derivative of $\frac{1}{2-x}$ but then what?...

Comment: Really? This isn't explained in your calculus textbook? How to find an n-th derivative?

Answer (score 5):

As you wrote in your comment to @Florian's answer, you got some of the first derivatives 
$$ y'(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}, y''(x) = -\frac 2{(1-x)^3}, y'''(x) = \frac{2\cdot 3}{(1-x)^4}, \ldots $$
Now you have to identify a pattern in these derivatives ... some hints:

- alternating signs, $+$ for odd orders (1,3,5,...), $-$ for even ones
- in the numerator we have $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots$ upto what number? Can you link it to the order of the derivative?
- in the denominator, we have $(1-x)^?$. How is the exponent linked to the order of the derivative.

Your pattern gives you a guess for $y^{(n)}(x) = \ldots$. Then prove you are right by induction (differentiating your guess).

Comment: Are you sure you have the signs correct?

Answer (score 3):

$y^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$-th derivative of $y$.

Comment: I wrote the equation as y=(1-x)^-1
I get y'=(1-x)^2 ..and y" =-2* (1-x)^-3..how do i write this in terms of y^n?